# onPress button running while loading page

Tags: react-native

I send data to my API and then call the page DataManifest.js

On this page I just call the `import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';`

And I have a button that when clicked will go to `index.js` page

```
<Button
  onPress={ Actions.index() }
  title="Return"
  color="#841584"
/>
```

However, when loading the page it calls directly to `index.js` without clicking the button

And returns the following debugger warning:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods
>   should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects
>   are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: try ```onPress={ () => { Actions.index() } }```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what onPress is. It is a function. You need to pass it a function. What you was originally passing was the result of running that function. You don't want to pass the result of running the function, you want a function. So you would pass `onPress={Actions.index}`. If you needed to manage the parameters you call the function with, then you can wrap it in another function and manage it that way. Like the other answer suggests `onPress={ () => { Actions.index() } }`. But you see, that is returning a function, not the result of running a function.

Answer (score 1):

From

```
onPress={ Actions.index() }
```

To

```
onPress={ () => { Actions.index() } }
```

Comment: Or `onPress={Actions.index}`